# No "Quick Edit" links on categories admin page

Tags: categories

The "quick edit" links are not displayed in the admin categories page.
How do I restore them?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's a plugin "WPB Accordion Menu or Category PRO".
I've disabled it and it's working again.